# Java - Sending values from Subclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I need some help sending a value from my Subclass to my Superclass.

```
Public class A {

protected int GameSize;

public void setButtons(){   
        for(int row = 0; row < GameSize; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < GameSize; col++) {       
                buttons[row][col] = new PlayerButton();
                buttons[row][col].button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
                buttons[row][col].player = row+""+col;
                buttons[row][col].button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/img/empty.png"));
                box.add(buttons[row][col].button);
            }
        }   

        box.setVisible(true);   

    }

}



public class B extends A {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      Object source = a.getSource();
      JButton pressedButton = (JButton)source;  
      if(pressedButton.getText() == "Start Game") {

       GameSize = Integer.parseInt(GameSizeBox.getSelectedItem().toString().replaceAll("x.*","")); 
       if((setplayername1.getText().length() > 0) && (setplayername2.getText().length() > 0)){
        StartNewGame(setplayername1.getText(), setplayername2.getText(), GameSize);
       }
      }
      if(pressedButton.getText() == "Exit") {
       System.exit(0);
      }

     } 
  }
```

I want to be able to use the GameSize, that I changed in class B, in class A. How do I work around this problem? To clarify, I have a variable ( GameSize ) in class A that is protected, and I change this variable in class B and I want to "reuse" the changed GameSize in the forloops in class A.

Thanks.

Comment: After GameSize is changed in class `B`, calling `setButtons` in class `A` should reflect modified `GameSize`. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: The GameSize is null if I try to call it.

Comment: an int cannot be null

Comment: Show us an SSCCE. The code you have there doesn't compile, and it's impossible to explain you clearly why it behaves as it behaves. The only thing I can cay is that the setButtons() method is called before the actionPerformed() method is called, and thus sees the initial value of GameSize. Also, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry about the unclear code. But you were exactly right, the setButtons was called before actionPerformed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, You want to change value in class A after it change in class B.
Simply after create object A:

```
A Class_a = new A();
Class_a.GameSize= /value from B/
```

You can also build constuctor in class A, that set value in GameSize, and call in in class B by using super()
In class A

```
A(int a){
GameSize=a;
}
```

and in class B

```
super(/* here new value */)
```